# Nginx redirection conflicts with other ports

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, nginx

My situations is as follows:

- app 1 running at: server.domain.com (**192.168.1.3**)
- app 2 running at: server.domain.com:8080 (**192.168.1.2**)

My router is set up to route requests on port 80 to app 1 and port 8080 to app 2.

So far so good, this scenario has been working *for ages*.

Recently I tried switching to nginx and I decided to redirect http traffic to https traffic for app 1. 
I set up a container with nginx and am using the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# main server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /path to cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path to cert;
    ssl_dhparam /path to cert;
    ssl_ciphers '';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php7-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

This successfully redirects http to https and app 1 works as expected.
However when trying to visit app 2 I will also be redirected to https (which it shouldn't, app 2 doesn't support it)

Now I already figured out **why** this happens.
Google Chrome has a cache so when I visit the non-https url it gets a 301 redirect to the https version. It saves this in it's cache and now thinks I always want https regardless of the port.

The workaround I've found is going to chrome://net-internals and clearing the cache there. Opening app 2 then succeeds but after visiting app 1 I end up in the same loop all over again.

I've tried several default fixes found all over the net but none of them have worked thus far.

Anyone know what I have to put in my config to fix this?

***ps: cert paths, domain names and ports are fake representations of the real situation***

Answer (score 0):

First off it would be helpful if in the nginx config you label which server definition corresponds to App 1 and App 2, because it appears there may be a mix up in the configuration. You are also missing some configuration, such as listening to port 8080. So first I'll clarify the requirements you clearly stated for both apps:

App 1:

- Listens on port 80
- Uses SSL

App 2:

- Listens on port 8080
- Does not use SSL / doesn't support it.

So I'd recommend config closer to:

```
# Corresponds better to app 2 given your requirements
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    # NOTE: You may want to listen for certain routes,  without redirect EG
    # location /foo/* { . . . }

    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
}

# main server block - app 1
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    . . . # The rest of your definition here is fine for an SSL server
}
```

My main point here is that the server block on port 80 as you've defined it above is just a redirect machine to https, hardcoded. This block as you've defined it contradicts the requirements that you "route requests on port 80 to app 1" and you "use SSL for app 1" since your SSL configuration is actually in the second server definition. What you've set up in the first server definition is actually a pattern used to [force ssl redirects](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx) leaving you in a position where you'll never serve non-ssl HTTP traffic. This might clear up the issue somewhat; perhaps I can help more once the server blocks more closely match the stated requirements.

Finally noting that it is possible to listen to multiple ports and route to http and https traffic within one server definition block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    # can force some routes to be ssl or non ssl accordingly 
}
```

Configuration like this may be more ideal if both app servers are hosted on the same machine using the same nginx service.

Comment: I specified ip addresses to convey the fact that they aren't on the same server, sorry if this wasn't too clear. 

Ideally I'd want the server running nginx to ignore anything but app1's requests. (which would come in on port 80/443 not port 8080)

I suspect it's doing just that but it's sending a 301 to chrome which puts that in its cache and subsequently redirects all the other ports to the https version.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! This fix may be as simple as changing the 301 (permanent redirect) which chrome caches to a 302. More info at http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects or http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects

Comment: Sorry about that, that was actually one of my first thoughts but it seems to remember that as well :/

Let me try it again though, might've made a mistake

Comment: Perhaps specify a no-cache header in nginx with `add_header "Cache-Control" "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";`

Comment: I tried both but it seems to ignore it once again (I tried a different browser just to verify)

Comment: Okay I think what you want is something similar to what is demonstrated in http://askubuntu.com/a/604417, EG
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`

`server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}`

Comment: I'll go on and remove this answer if that doesn't help because I want your question to get the attention it needs.

Comment: Adding a server with 8080 doesn't work either unfortunately. You have been great, thanks for all the help man.